# How to share the cookies that CrawlSpider holded to the webview request(pywebkit)?

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, scrapy

I am crawling some pages (under the same domain) by Scrapy.

There are some special pages which are generated by JS, so I use the [ScrapyJS](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs) and load the pages in webview so the JS could be executed. BUT the webpages loaded in the webview is fresh-request to the website. The response in the webview will redirect the pages to the site login page, that 's not what I want.

In my opinion, I have logined the site in my MyTestSpider. If the request of the webview could hold/share/read the cookies from MyTestSpider, it would make the JS-generated pages performs well just like what it should be by correctly user login, not redirected to the site login page.

which what I have:
    class MyTestSpider(CrawlSpider):

```
    def start_requests(self):
        self.prelogin()

    def prelogin(self):
        //login prepares

    def login(self):
        //login the website and hold the cookie

    def parse_item(self, response):
        //parse the items
```

Is there anyone got a better solution to this issue ?
Any help would be appraciated...  :p

Answer (score 0):

see this [scrapy feature](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html#job-directory)

> To start a spider with persistence supported enabled, run it like this:

```
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1
```

> Then, you can stop the spider safely at any time (by pressing Ctrl-C or sending a signal), and resume it later by issuing the same command:

```
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand how to solve my issue with the scrapy-jobs feature. could you please just explain the details of it ?